# Apply default WPF style

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a global style that sets all my `TextBox` styles, but in some cases I want to revert *just* the Foreground color to the original non-custom-style color.  I tried using `{TemplateBinding Foreground}` inside the specific `TextBoxes` that I wanted to revert.  It didn't end up being valid XAML and I'm not sure that's the right way anyhow.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a few ways this could be done.  If you look at the [Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) on the MSDN
then you can see that the Forground set in ways 1-8 will override the `Foreground` from a default style.  The easiest way being just to set the local value in the `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox Foreground="Red" />
```

Another thing that you can do is use the `'BasedOn'` property of styles to override the other versions.  This does require giving a key value to your default style, but that can then be used to also apply the default like in this example:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           x:Key="myTextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
    <!-- Style applies to all TextBoxes -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource myTextBoxStyle}" />


<TextBox Text="Hello">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource myTextBoxStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

**Edit:**
In the case that the default style is applying a value and you want to revert it to the base value there are a few ways I can think of, off hand, to get this behavior.  You can't, that I know of, bind back to the default theme value in a generic manner.

We can however do some other things.  If we need the style to not apply some properties, we can set the style to `{x:Null}`, thus stopping the default style from applying.  Or we can give the element it's own style that does not inherit from the base style and then re-apply only the setters that we need:

```
        <TextBox Text="Hello" Style="{x:Null}" />
        <TextBox Text="Hello">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                            Value="Bold" />
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

We could modify the default style so that the Foreground will only be set on certain conditions, such as the Tag being a certain value.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           x:Key="myTextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Bold" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Tag"
                     Value="ApplyForeground">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

   <TextBox Text="Hello" />
    <TextBox Text="Hello" Tag="ApplyForeground" />
```

Comment: In your example, I don't want to have to specify "Blue".  I want to do something like <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />. I want its default w/o explicitly saying Value="Black".

Comment: Ah, that's a little different indeed.  I'll edit my answer to handle that case.

Comment: Turns out my issue was a little different from what I described. It was really a matter of styling being applied to TextBoxes in a ListView. But I'll accept this answer to give you some SO juice since you did such a great job explaining. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, glad it's solved. Also, I found a better way to assign the BasedOn property of a style.  If you use BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" then the style will automatically be based on whatever the default applied style for that type is.  I think that's a lot better then having to create two styles like in my first code example.

Comment: Thanks very much for adding the comment about `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"`. I was trying to find an alternative to the two-style approach (which your actual answer shows), and stumbled across the Q&A here. Your comment above provided _exactly_ the tip I needed! IMHO, you should add that detail to the answer itself (maybe leaving the two-style approach in also as an example, which might help others find this answer more easily).